# Dynamic links with Jekyll and JSON

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I have an API that I have used to generate individual JSON files per an individual merchant.

I am using Jekyll. I would like to be able to generate a dynamic link that renders a template for each individual JSON file. For instance,

I want the user to be able to click a link, and they are then taken to a page (the Navbar should stay out) and the liquid templating engine loops over the JSON file and renders what I want on that specific template.

What is the best way to do this in Jekyll? I have seen where folks hard code the URLS but I would like to have the url be dynamic and Jekyll should be able to render an extra link if a new JSON file shows up.

To restate:

I want to link to individual pages and render their content from their individual JSON files.

I have a basic understanding of how Jekyll works, and get the _data folder and site matter, but the problem is site matter is not dynamic and I don’t want to hardcore any of the links. So far I am just getting a handle on the problem and would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Kindly,

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Jekyll's purpose is to generate **static** websites, like for simple blogging, landpages, portfolios, etc. However, you seems to want a **dynamic** webpage. In this case I would suggest you to not use Jekyll at all. It is not like you can't get it done with Jekyll, but I don't see why you should get out of your way to use it.

If you really want to use Jekyll, the way I can think of is with AJAX. Which means you would dynamically change your page with javascript through scripts added in the templates of your pages ("_layouts" folder). You can use JQuery to make your life easier should you choose this approach.

In conclusion, the "right direction" in this case would be to avoid Jekyll. The "best way to do this in Jekyll", honestly, I don't know, but you could achieve what you want using the aforementioned method.

Edit:
I thought that the OP wanted a dynamic website whose content would be get from HTTP requests to his API. Turns out the he apparently has a bunch of JSON files stored in the "data" folder, and then use this files to generate the static website. For those interested, if my assumption was correct, my proposed solution would be something like this:

- In my example I use [{JSON} Placeholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) "fake" API and react standalone library.

#### _layouts/default.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Load react, react-dom and babel -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/babel" src="/public/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="index">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### public/index.js

```js
function Hyperlink(props) {
    const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${props.id}`
    return (
       <a href={url}>{props.title}</a>
    )
}

class Index extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {posts: []}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        xhr.send(null);
        const that = this;
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            const DONE = 4;
            const HTTP_OK = 200;
            if(xhr.readyState == DONE) {
                if(xhr.status == HTTP_OK) {
                    that.setState({
                        posts: JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log(xhr.status);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {
                    this.state.posts.map((post, idx) => <li key={idx}><Hyperlink id={post.id} title={post.title} /></li>)
                }
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Index />
   , document.getElementById("index")
);
```

#### Result

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFa2Q.png)

With this you just need to have a root element (can be any div) to put your your dynamicaly generated in.

Comment: Thank you, but Jekyll is a requirement for the project. If you could expound on what you were saying or if you have more information into how this can be done by generating data files and then reading data from those files.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure this out.  Here is a small code snippet of how I handled it:

```
`{% for item in site.data._json %}
{% if page.title == item[0] %}
{% for content in item[1][1] %}`
```

I have all of my JSON files stored in the _data/_json directory.

I have links that match the names of the files stored in a merchants directory in the root.  An HTML file is built for each item in the _JSON directory.

Explaining the loop at the top:

1. First I loop over all of my JSON files in _json.
2. Next, I check to see if the current page title (which is
   what is specified in the merchants directory, specified
   inside an individual HTML file for that page, with
   frontmatter, "title".
3. If the page title matches the item[0], this is the
   current name of the file, then I can get access to that
   content in the individual file for that specific template.

If you have any questions reply here.